# AlarmManager one time alarm does not fire

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to trigger a one-time alarm with the following, which is basically a replicate from https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html (second ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP example).

This is inside public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener:

```
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), MuteReceiver.class);
        AlarmManager alm = (AlarmManager)(this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
        alm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60*1000, 
            alarmIntent);
        Log.d("MainActivity", "alarm set");
    }
```

public class MuteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver is like this:

```
public MuteReceiver() {
    Log.d("MuteReceiver", "constructed");
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    boolean started = prefs.getBoolean(MuteService.STARTED, false);
    Log.d("MuteReceiver", "Started=" + started);
}
```

I pressed the button in the Fragment, saw the log message "alarm set", but after one minute (and much later), still no log about MuteReceiver being constructed or MuteReceiver started (in onReceive)

Comment: Have you registered `MuteReceiver ` in the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a guaranteed list file with a registered broadcast

Comment: I think you meant an entry in AndroidManifest.xml.  I've added and it worked. I'll accept your answer but there are new problems, perhaps I'll try to fix before posting another question.